# Are thought bottles reusable?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

I was reading this item on page 150 of *Complete Arcane* and it does not specify either way. Are these a one time use or a reusable item?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**It is reusable.**

Generally speaking, unless an item specifies that it is consumed, it isn't. Not to mention this item is a bottle (albeit a magical one), which is *by definition* a reusable container.

Several min/max-ing boards discussing this item appear to confirm my assumptions (
[Site One](http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?107098-Complete-Arcane-Though-Bottle-abuse-and-Magic-Item-Creation) [Site Two](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?217819-Nesting-Thought-Bottles-millions-of-wishes) ).

Spoiler alert: most people suggest ripping that page out of your book anyway, because this item is severely broken.

Comment: It was more or less for the use of memory storage and not for the exp housing...

Comment: No judgments here :)

Comment: My Dm will probably over rule and say they are one time use even though we don't associate xp cost with wish or item creation.

Comment: The important part is that you're all trying to have fun; as long as you're both aiming for that, I wouldn't worry about it.